# SSRS fitting Tablix to exported pdf page only in portrait mode

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I create  a Matrix within an SSRS report. Usually, the matrix will fix to a standard page in portrait mode, however in this cases where the length of the columns will exceed a page. Is there a way to have SSRS render the report to a PDF where this Matrix would auto-size and shrink all of it's contents, for example font, column widths to fit within a page? I don't want to shrink all objects in the SSRS report to fix the page, just the width of the Matrix and no Landscape

[image]

[image]